# Python mocked exception not being caught

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Struggling to succinctly describe this in the title...

I have a module I want to test:

*mod.py*:

```
import subprocess
class MyStuff(object):
    def my_fun(self):
        try:
            print subprocess
            out = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "pirates"])
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            print "caught exception"
```

And the test module *test_mod.py*:

```
import unittest
import mock
from mod import MyStuff
import subprocess

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.patched_subprocess = mock.patch(
            'mod.subprocess', autospec=True)
        self.mock_subprocess = self.patched_subprocess.start()
        self.my_stuff = MyStuff()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.patched_subprocess.stop()

    def test_my_fun(self):
        self.mock_subprocess.check_output = mock.Mock(
            side_effect=subprocess.CalledProcessError(0, "hi", "no"))
        with self.assertRaises(subprocess.CalledProcessError):
            out = self.my_stuff.my_fun()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I then run `python test_mod.py` and I see the following output:

```
<NonCallableMagicMock name='subprocess' spec='module' id='140654009377872'>
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.007s

OK
```

I'm pleased that the subprocess object has been mocked, but why is the `print "caught exception"` statement *not* executed? I'm guessing it's because the real exception getting throw in `test_mod.subprocess.CalledProcessException` and not `subprocess.CalledProcessException` as I intend, but I'm not sure how to resolve that. Any suggestion? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this eventually...

The problem was I was mocking the *entire* subprocess module, which included the `CalledProcessError` exception! That's why it didn't seem to match the exception I was raising in my test module, because it was a completely different object.

The fix is to mock just `subprocess.check_output`, D'oh!